# Definite article in the headlines containing ‘of’

Tags: articles, headline-english

I’d like to know if we should keep an initial 'THE' in the titles of scientific papers, articles or finale papers of students, if they contain 'of'?

For instance:

> **The** concept of truth in the work by Dostoyevsky.

Should we keep the initial 'the' or leave it out like we do in newspapers titles? Or we should keep it because of OF?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: “Concept of truth in work by Dostoyevsky” sounds rather Russian. Putting one definite article back doesn’t seem to help much, though more so for the second definite article than the first.

Comment: Well, it is supposed to be a translation of the headline of a Russian final paper at one of the universities. And some experts argue whether there should be THE at the beginning or not.

Comment: Which one of Dostoyevsky's works is the paper about?  Why don't you name it in the title?  (Or, rather, you should consider replacing the prepositional phrase with something else that says what you really mean.)  Also, the title of a paper is not generally called a "headline," but a "title."  Headlines are for newspapers.

Comment: The "of" is a red herring. It has nothing to do with the answer to the question. There is no "of" in the original anyway, because there is no "of" in Russian. It's just rendered that way in English, but if you replace the Russian phrase with something else that is not translated using an "of", the question of whether you should omit the initial "the" still persists. Also @Lawrence: the singular "work" makes no sense in Russian, either. It'd have to be plural there as well. Or a collective noun like "opus". Just like in English. So yeah. I suggest you post the original title.

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear to me exactly what your title is supposed to convey, but I assume you mean:

> Dostoyevsky wrote some books, and this article looks at the concept of "truth" in them.

In English we would normally call Dostoyevsky's books "the works **of** Dostoyevsky" (although "the work **of** Dostoyevsky" can be used too). Because you are referring to specific things you always use the definite article.

"The work **by** Dostoyevsky would mean *one* work, i.e. a single book.

The presence of 'of' in 'concept of truth' makes no difference. 'Concept of truth' is a noun phrase, and any noun phrase could be substituted without changing the grammar. For example "Female characters in the works of Dostoyevsky" or "Political ideas in the works of Dostoyevsky".

EDIT: The question appears to be asking about the initial "the".

The first thing to note is that titles are not the same as headlines. Headlines are often space-constrained, and it is common to omit short words that are not needed for understanding, even if that violates the rules of grammar. But titles of articles are not space-constrained (at least not to the point where omitting short words make a difference). Titles are usually grammatically correct noun phrases, and in this case the initial "the" is necessary.

(You can often tell if a title is grammatically correct by imaging the words "This article is about..." at the front of it, and checking that the result makes a grammatically correct sentence. The word "the" would definitely be necessary in such a sentence.)

Comment: Thanks for your reply but I meant another thing. Should we say in my example The concept of... or just “concept of” if it is a title?

Answer (score -1):

A formal title, literary:

- The Dostoyevskian Concept of Truth
- The Concept of Truth in Dostoyevsky

There is no need to say: in the work of Dostoyevsky here.

Sorry for the lack of explanation, this is just a style thing.

For example:

[image: Truth in Aquinas]

> Provocative and sophisticated, Truth in Aquinas is a fascinating
>   re-evaluation of a key area - truth - **in the work of Thomas Aquinas.**
>   John Milbank and Catherine Pickstock's provocative but strongly argued
>   position is that many of the received views of Aquinas as philosopher
>   and theologian are wrong.

Just add: The Concept of.....for Doestoyevsky

Yes, in English, when you have something like **the X of Y**, the definite article is imperative:

You could have: **concepts of truth**, with an s, **a concept of truth** with an indefinite article, and **the concept of truth** (meaning a single definite concept) **but just: "concept of truth" is not grammatical.**

Comment: "there is no need to say 'in the work of Dostoyevsky' here": I would go farther: there is a need not to say it, because it seems to say something other than what the author means.  I would also suggest that if the author is uncomfortable using "Dostoyevsky" to mean "Dostoyevsky's body of work" then one might consider saying "Dostoyevsky's oeuvre" or indeed "Dostoyevsky's work."  But your suggestion seems more idiomatic, and I would suggest that the author should endeavor to get over any such discomfort.

Comment: I disagree. "The concept of truth in the Works of Dostoyevsky" means the concept of truth as found in the (literary) works he produced. It does not cover what Dostoyevsky personally thought about truth, what he said about it in private conversation etc. Both of the alternatives you cite could include his private concept of truth outside his works. Precision is good. Vagueness is bad.

Answer (score -1):

> For instance: "The Concept of Truth in the Work by Dostoyevsky." Should we keep the initial 'the' or leave it out like we do in newspapers titles?

There is no real choice. **Concept** is a singular countable noun and, as such, (and with a few exceptions that we do not need to consider), it must have a determiner - This is basic grammar.

Newspaper titles are irrelevant. They bear absolutely no relationship  to the titles of academic papers.

Academic titles are not restricted by the space on the page and do not need to have shortened forms. Nor do they need to grab the reader's attention in order to encourage them to buy the newspaper.

PS, the title is strange unless you are referring to one particular work and, if you are, then the title is wrong and needs to include the name of the work.